# How can I execute local script on remote machine and include arguments?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, options

I have written a script that runs fine when executed locally:

```
./sysMole -time Aug 18 18
```

The arguments **"-time"**, **"Aug"**, **"18"**, and **"18"** are successfully passed on to the script.

Now, this script is designed to be executed on a remote machine but, from a local directory on the local machine. Example:

```
ssh root@remoteServer "bash -s" < /var/www/html/ops1/sysMole
```

That also works fine. But the problem arises when I try to include those aforementioned arguments **(-time Aug 18 18)**, for example:

```
ssh root@remoteServer "bash -s" < /var/www/html/ops1/sysMole -time Aug 18 18
```

After running that script I get the following error:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Invalid argument
bash: no job control in this shell
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, this greatly frustrating.

Comment: "Bash -s" is one of the ways you can execute an script from standard input (ie. a file).

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-run-a-local-shell-script-on-a-remote-ssh-server/

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You were pretty close with your example. It works just fine when you use it with arguments such as these.

***Sample script:***

```
$ more ex.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 $2
```

***Example that works:***

```
$ ssh serverA "bash -s" < ./ex.bash "hi" "bye"
hi bye
```

But it fails for these types of arguments:

```
$ ssh serverA "bash -s" < ./ex.bash "--time" "bye"
bash: --: invalid option
...
```

#### What's going on?

The problem you're encountering is that the argument, `-time`, or `--time` in my example, is being interpreted as a switch to `bash -s`. You can pacify `bash` by terminating it from taking any of the remaining command line arguments for itself using the `--` argument.

Like this:

```
$ ssh root@remoteServer "bash -s" -- < /var/www/html/ops1/sysMole -time Aug 18 18
```

#### Examples

*#1:*

```
$ ssh serverA "bash -s" -- < ./ex.bash "-time" "bye"
-time bye
```

*#2:*

```
$ ssh serverA "bash -s" -- < ./ex.bash "--time" "bye"
--time bye
```

*#3:*

```
$ ssh serverA "bash -s" -- < ./ex.bash --time "bye"
--time bye
```

*#4:*

```
$ ssh  < ./ex.bash serverA "bash -s -- --time bye"
--time bye
```

**NOTE:** Just to make it clear that wherever the redirection appears on the command line makes no difference, because `ssh` calls a remote shell with the concatenation of its arguments anyway, quoting doesn't make much difference, except when you need quoting on the remote shell like in example *#4:*

```
$ ssh  < ./ex.bash serverA "bash -s -- '<--time bye>' '<end>'"
<--time bye> <end>
```

Comment: you are an Genius! What do I have to do to get to your level? I have alot of work cut out. Thanks so much.

Comment: @AllenD - just keep asking questions, and try and participate on the site as much as you can. I always try and learn something new each day. Before your question I didn't know how to do this either. 8-). Thanks for your question!

Comment: note that the redirection can appear at any point in the command: for example `bash -s -- --time bye < ./ex.bash` or even `< ./ex.bash bash -s -- --time bye`. this is because the shell first takes out the redirection instruction (regardless of where it is in the command), then sets up the redirection, then executes the rest of the command line with the redirection in place.

Comment: @sim I'm trying to do this exact same thing, but from within a script, not from the command line.  Any idea of how to do this? For some reason, enclosing your exact answer in backticks does not work at all. It instead runs the script specified locally, and the output is sent as a command to the bash over ssh

Comment: @krb686 - I'd ask it as a new Q.

Comment: Sure already did, it's located here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187960/is-it-possible-to-send-a-heredoc-over-ssh-to-a-remote-host-from-inside-a-script

Comment: I knew "bash -s" but I didn't know how to stop bash from interpreting other switches which were not meant for bash. Useful tip.

Comment: @slm thank you for the great answer. Is it possible to pass file as an argument. Say run `ssh user@server 'some_script.sh' ' <  file_input` . The first part would work but how to make the `some_script.sh` on `server` to read `file_input` on the local pc

Comment: single `-` is enough  :  `bash -s - < ./ex.bash --time "bye"`

Answer (score 8):

## On Handling Arbitrary Arguments

If you're really only using a single string, ie. `-time Aug 18 18`, then you can simply hardcode it, and existing answers tell you how to do that adequately. On the other hand, if you need to pass unknown arguments through (like a message to be displayed on the other system, or the name of a file created where end-users could control its name), then more care is needed.

---

#### With `bash` or `ksh` as `/bin/sh`

If your remote `/bin/sh` is provided by bash or ksh, you can safely do the following with an untrusted argument list, such that even malicious names (like `$(rm -rf $HOME).txt`) can be passed as arguments safely:

```
runRemote() {
  local args script

  script=$1; shift

  # generate eval-safe quoted version of current argument list
  printf -v args '%q ' "$@"

  # pass that through on the command line to bash -s
  # note that $args is parsed remotely by /bin/sh, not by bash!
  ssh user@remote-addr "bash -s -- $args" < "$script"
}
```

---

#### With Any POSIX-Compliant `/bin/sh`

To be safe against sufficiently malicious argument data (attempting to take advantage of the non-POSIX compliant quoting used by `printf %q` in bash when nonprintable characters are present in the string being escaped) even with a `/bin/sh` that is baseline-POSIX (such as `dash` or `ash`), it gets a bit more interesting:

```
runRemote() {
  local script=$1; shift
  local args
  printf -v args '%q ' "$@"
  ssh user@remote-addr "bash -s" <<EOF

  # pass quoted arguments through for parsing by remote bash
  set -- $args

  # substitute literal script text into heredoc
  $(< "$script")

EOF
}
```

---

#### Usage (for either of the above)

The functions given above can then be invoked as:

```
# if your time should be three arguments
runRemote /var/www/html/ops1/sysMole -time Aug 18 18
```

...or...

```
# if your time should be one string
runRemote /var/www/html/ops1/sysMole -time "Aug 18 18"
```

Comment: Nice script. But beware that globbing (expansion of *) always runs on local machine, the bash running the script. 'runRemote rsync --exclude="*.log" /from/* /to' will always get an unquoted * expanded by the bash running the script, ie. on the local machine.

Its possible to disable globing with 'set -f'. But it doesn't really help, as * and "*.log" both just becomes strings containing a * so we cannot tell the difference afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the command(s) in quotes as follows:

```
ssh myserver "date +\"Date: %Y%m%d %H:%M\";printf \"Uptime: \";uptime;printf \"uname: \";uname -a"
Date: 20200409 20:02
Uptime:  20:02:29 up 66 days, 55 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.05, 0.08
uname: Linux zltcmtn23aecc1rx7322 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Connection to 105.31.182.217 closed.
```

Answer (score -3):

say a.a is a local file that contains ls

`$ssh servername "cat | bash" < a.a`

change 127.0.0.1 to whatever your remote ip is

these two give a message about pseudo tty  allocation but they work.

`$ cat a.a | ssh 127.0.0.1`

`$ ssh 127.0.0.1 <a.a`

Or

`$ cat a.a | ssh 127.0.0.1 bash  or`

`$ ssh 127.0.0.1 bash < a.a`

Comment: I'm struggling to see in how far this answers the question.

Comment: The quality and formatting is doubtful.  I don't see any new useful information that's not present in the accepted answer either.

Comment: @JuliePelletier  I gave some 'cat' examples not in the accepted answer. It's good to know alternative ways of doing things.

Comment: That's not a good thing; your cats are useless.

Comment: @Scott To say they're useless is ambiguous.. They work in passing the script a.a to the remote machine.   It may be that it's probably  unnecessary..and I see a big flaw with my answer, in that I didn't look into/cover  passing arguments, and the question requests that..  I found my first example interesting.. the shell passes a.a to ssh which then sees cat awaiting stdin and it passes it to that, at least seems that way to me anyway!

Comment: Oh my goodness. I left out the link to [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) because I assumed that everybody had at least heard of the phrase by now; apparently that was a bad assumption on my part.