# Is it possible to send a HEREDOC over ssh to a remote host from inside a script running locally?

Tags: ssh, io-redirection, csh

I essentially want to run a script on machine A which will SSH into machine B, execute commands on B, and return the output to machine A.

So I am creating a csh script to do this, hopefully, if it's possible.

For instance, this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3872762/1701574) works from command line:

```
ssh user@host << 'ENDSSH'
ls -l
ENDSSH
```

I can verify it is running the ls on the remote and not locally.

However I want to be able to do this within the backticks, inside my csh script running locally. Would that be possible?

I know it is possible to SSH in and run a script that is on the remote, but that is not my case.

I have also heard it is possible to send a second script stored locally over the SSH (which I also have not figured out), but I like the idea of having all of the commands inside the original script, hence the HEREDOC.

I know it is a pretty particular question, but if there is a way, it would be very cool to know how.

**Things that don't work**

**1)**

```
`ssh user@host<<'ENDSSH'`
`echo "ls -l"`
`echo "ENDSSH"`
```

This gives the error:

`stty: standard input: Invalid argument.`
`stty: standard input: Invalid argument.`
`Warning: Command not found`

And then it runs `ls -l` locally, and then it tried to run `ENDSSH` locally and of course fails with command not found.

**2)**

```
`ssh user@host<<'ENDSSH'`
echo "ls -l"
echo "ENDSSH"
```

Same problem as above, except it only displays `ls -l` and `ENDSSH` as text. Makes sense...since the HEREDOC portion failed.

**3)** 3-5 aren't exactly what I asked about, but still trying just to get even the basic case working.

```
`ssh user@host ls-l`
```

This returns `total: Command not found.`
Yeah, I have no clue where that's coming from.

**4)**

```
`cat ./test.csh | ssh user@host`
```

Also returns the same as attempt #1

**5)**

```
`cat ./test.csh | ssh -t user@host`
```

Same as #1 and 4.

I am beginning to exhaust other solutions from stackoverflow/Ubuntu/serverfault...etc.  Most people ask about how to run their script on a remote from command line, not how to run commands on a remote from a locally running script.

**Edit**

Well I think I have part of the problem figured out.  With case 3 from above for example, what happens is `ls -l` runs locally, and the first part of the output is then sent over SSH as a command.

I noticed this because I tried `ssh user@host $CMD`, with `$CMD` set to `"whoami"`. The output was `username: Command not found`, and then I realized the `total` is from the ls output. Still not sure about how to solve this, though

Comment: Have you tried ? I mostly use scp && ssh  to check any problem with connectivity or password/ssh key. However your solution looks ok.

Comment: @Archemar See the last section I have added.

Comment: Re your Edit comment, that's not really correct. You have case 3 as ```ssh user@host ls -l` ``. What this does is run `ssh user@host ls -l`, which in turn runs `ls -l` on the remote host. The resulting output is grabbed by the backticks and evaluated locally, which because there's nothing to collect that output, ends up being executed as a local command.

Comment: @roaima Okay so I had it switched around, so it runs `ls -l` remotely, and the output locally, as opposed to `ls -l` locally, and the output remotely?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you wrap the entire command that you want executed inside backticks it's likely you'll get the correct solution. There are issues regarding the evaluation of variables and other interpolated elements, but I'll put those to one side for a moment.

However, I'm not entirely sure why you want anything in backticks. Your Question says you want to run a local script remotely. Your first example does this.

```
ssh -q user@host << ENDSSH
hostname
ls -l
id
ENDSSH
```

Perhaps you want to get the output of the remote execution into a variable? It doesn't say that anywhere in the Question, but you'd do it like this (`bash`)

```
result=$(ssh user@host <<'ENDSSH'
hostname
id
ENDSSH
)
...
echo "$result"
```

Or, since you mentioned `csh`, like this

```
set result = `ssh -q user@host` <<ENDSSH
hostname
id
ENDSSH
...
echo "$result"
```

Note that for the `csh` variant all output lines are concatenated together.

I see that you have reported an error, `stty: standard input: Invalid argument.` This is probably occurring because you have an `stty` command in your login script on the remote server. This should be wrapped in a test for an interactive shell. In `bash` you would do something like this:

```
if test -n "$PS1"
then
    # Interactive setup here
    stty ...
fi
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct I will eventually want to store the results of the commands run on the remote inside variables in the locally running script.  Your `csh` solution is not working, unfortunately. This still results in errors: `stty: standard input: Invalid argument`. I added an edit to my question at the end with some interesting information, not sure if you saw that yet, but there is a clue.

Comment: @krb686 Please see the update for `stty`. If you have the option, I would strongly recommend that you stop writing `csh` script and use `sh`/`bash` instead. There are a number of significant problems with using `csh` as a scripting language so it really would benefit you to learn `sh`/`bash`, even if you prefer `csh` for interactive use.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that.  I will check that out in a minute. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not certain what your trying to do, but here is something that worked for me.

```
R=`ssh -t hostname <<EOF
ls -l
EOF`
```

Note that I don't close the backtick until after EOF and use -t option to create a virtual TTY even though stdio is being redirected.

Comment: Hmm, so the input to the heredoc needs to be within the backtick. Now how do I separate those commands in the heredoc on separate lines of the csh script? This just complains about missing a backtick, since the backtick is started on the first line before ssh, and ended after EOF

Comment: Okay so you need a `"\"` at the end of each line to continue the heredoc.  Interesting, this almost works. It complains with: `ls: cannot access EOF: No such file or directory`. It thinks the `EOF` is an argument to whatever command is before it. Also tried this with `whoami` and it says `whoami: extra operand EOF`

Comment: @roaima Thanks, I have been hearing that in multiple places.  If you have a good reference, I'd like to read it! I have been learning (and prefer) bash, but I may potentially be forced to use `csh` for certain things.  I am not entirely sure of that, though, and if there is a way to successfully do this with `bash`, I would definitely like that info as well, if anyone has it

Comment: @krb686 we can't move comments. Just delete it and repost it at the right place.