# Bash use alternate dotfile?

Tags: bash, dot-files

I want to load my personalized bash file `~/.bashrc.me` instead of the one that is located at `~/.bashrc`

I was hoping there was something to the effect of:

```
bash --dotfile=.bashrc.me
```

Does such a thing exist?

I'd rather not mess around with `$SHELL`, I find that inelegant and it might complicate my end goal (to do with ssh'ing into a shared machine and piping in my dotfile, but that's another question).

EDIT: To use a local dotfile in a remote SSH session, see this: https://superuser.com/a/1078431/114723

Comment: Why couldn't you just modify the .bashrc file to have your custom things in it?  Unless you are using shared accounts it shouldn't affect other users.  Also if you are connecting over ssh the .bashrc file may not be sourced at all since it's not an interactive session it may only source .bash_profile and .profile.

Comment: If Michael's solution doesn't work for you, this thread may have some useful tips for you: https://serverfault.com/questions/164196/getting-a-custom-bashrc-available-in-ssh-session

Comment: Like you said, it's a shared machine with a single account and other colleagues won't like some of my customizations (e.g. the prompt, colors).

Comment: One thing I've done in the past on remote shared machines is to add a check to .bashrc looking at `$SSH_CONNECTION`, and if the connection is coming from my local workstation, source my config file. Similarly with a shared root account, if you get a root shell with `sudo -i`, you can use the `$SUDO_USER` to set up a custom per-user config.

Answer (score 3):

[`--init-file`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash):

> --init-file *filename*
>
> --rcfile *filename*
>
> Execute commands from *filename* (instead of `~/.bashrc`) in an interactive shell.

Comment: Perfect! Now I don't have to type `source .bashrc.me` every time (which often I'm too lazy to do).

Comment: Would this look for the file on the local machine or remote machine?  So if I did:  `ssh jbutryn@hostname < bash --rcfile /path/to/file /path/to/script` . would it pull both the script and rcfile from the local machine before sshing to the remote machine?

Comment: The remote machine can't read your files (but that command is ill-formed anyway).

Comment: Yea it doesn't work but if you do `ssh user@machine < /local/path/to/script` the local script will be executed against the remote machine.

Comment: There must be a way to get that to work but I can't figure it out either. Maybe a here document would help.https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187960/is-it-possible-to-send-a-heredoc-over-ssh-to-a-remote-host-from-inside-a-script

Comment: Here's a solution for the SSH part: https://superuser.com/a/1078431/114723 The trick is to use an environment variable to store the content of your local dotfile.