# How do I login to another UNIX machine and execute a shell script stored there?

Tags: linux-mint, remote-control

How do I login to another UNIX machine and execute a shell script stored there?

Answer (score 2):

From machine1, you can login to machine2 and execute a shell script there using SSH:

```
ssh myusername@machine2 /home/myusername/myscript.sh
```

Comment: And see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments

Comment: Thanks. But how to make it an automated one. That is whether the ssh connection (along with the password of the machine 2) and name of the scripts which i want to execute can be embedded in a single shell scripts, so that calling the scripts will automatically connect with the machine 2,and will execute the scripts residing there

Comment: Please edit your post to add all the necessary details.