# How to pass parameters to EXPECT using the '-c' option?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, expect

I'm using `expect` inside my bash script by using `expect -c`, but how do I pass parameters to it?

This is what I've tried:

```
FILE="myFile"
HOST="myhostname" 

/usr/bin/expect -c $FILE $HOST '
        set FILE [lindex $argv 0];
        set HOST [lindex $argv 1];
        send_user "$FILE $HOST"
        spawn scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  $FILE root@$HOST:/tmp/
        expect "assword:"
        send "password\r"
        interact'
```

If I create a separate expect script with the same contents but call it in bash like this:

```
myScript.expect $FILE $HOST
```

It works, but how do I do the same thing but using the `expect -c` option?

***Update:***

Also tried:

```
/usr/bin/expect -c '
        set FILE [lindex $argv 0];
        set HOST [lindex $argv 1];
        send_user "$FILE $HOST"
        spawn scp -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  $FILE root@$HOST:/tmp/
        expect "assword:"
        send "password\r"
        interact' $FILE $HOST
```

Comment: @steeldriver No, I'm getting `can't read "argv": no such variable` :(

Comment: I don't know about expect, but your command string is single quoted, so `$FILE` and `$HOST` won't expand in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. In the source code for `expect-5.45.4` we find in `exp_main_sub.c` at line 711

```
            case 'c': /* command */
                    exp_cmdlinecmds = TRUE;
                    rc = Tcl_Eval(interp,optarg);
                    ...
```

which handles `-c` code. `$argv` and friends are only created after the `-c` eval completes down at line 850 onwards

```
    /* collect remaining args and make into argc, argv0, and argv */
    sprintf(argc_rep,"%d",argc-optind);
    Tcl_SetVar(interp,"argc",argc_rep,0);
    expDiagLog("set argc %s\r\n",argc_rep);

    ...
    Tcl_SetVar(interp,"argv",args,0);
```

so `$argv` absolutely does not exist when the `-c` code runs.

One workaround is [Run a local expect script on a remote server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419193/run-a-local-expect-script-on-a-remote-server/419197#419197) which entails passing the TCL code in on standard input and then reading in `expect` the file `/dev/stdin`

```
$ echo puts \[lindex \$argv 1\] | expect /dev/stdin blee bla blu
bla
```

Another workaround is to toss the shell and write the whole thing in TCL

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set FILE [lindex $argv 0]
set HOST [lindex $argv 1]
...
```

And then `chmod +x` that and run it

```
./whatyoucalledtheabove somefile somehost
```

It would need to contain whatever else your current shell script does above the `expect` call...

Comment: Bummer, alrighty I'll create a separate script and call that. Thank you for the detailed explanation!