# How can I ssh into multiple password protected machines to reboot them?

Tags: ssh, reboot, expect

I'm trying to write a bash script to reboot multiple machines via ssh that are all password protected. I have all the IPs listed in a .txt file and want the script to read the IPs from there. I've been messing with the expect command since my mac does not have sshpass. Is there a way to do this without sshpass??

I have this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for server in 'testreboot.txt'; do
expect -c 'spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 
administrator@$server "sudo shutdown -r now"; expect "Password:"; send 
"password\r"; interact'
done
```

In testreboot.txt I simply have the IP address listed of a test machine. Is that ok or do I need to assign it to a variable? I keep getting a variable error when I try to run it.

Comment: It might be time to start looking into Python. I really like [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko#demo) for this sort of work. Also consider Ansible

Answer (score 2):

You have single quoted the string; this prevents the shell from
interpolating `$server`. TCL (which is what `expect` code is written in)
also uses the `$server` form to interpolate variables, but you have not
`set server ...` anywhere in your TCL code. Hence the error, as the
shell did not interpolate it nor did the TCL set it. One method would be
to double quote the TCL expression which will allow the shell to
interpolate in the shell `$server` variable:

```
$ server=example; expect -c 'puts $server'
can't read "server": no such variable
    while executing
"puts $server"
$ server=example; expect -c "puts $server"
example
$
```

However this will mean that any `"` in the TCL code will need to be
escaped to protect them from messing with the shell interpolation which
will probably get ugly real fast and will be hard to debug, especially
as the commands get longer and more complicated.

```
$ server=example; expect -c "puts \"a server named '$server'\""
a server named 'example'
$
```

Another option would be to read the argument into a TCL variable, but,
alas, the `-c` flag code of `expect` [has no access to the arguments list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427582/how-to-pass-parameters-to-expect-using-the-c-option)
in `char *argv[]` as the `-c` code is run before the arguments list is
made available for use by TCL. Therefore to use `$server` as a TCL
variable the script would need to be rewritten in TCL:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

set fh [open testreboot.txt r]

while {[gets $fh server] >= 0} {
    spawn -noecho ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5 \
       administrator@$server
    expect -ex "Password:"
    send "Hunter2\r"
    expect -ex {$ }
    send "sudo shutdown -r now\r"
    expect -ex "Password:"
    send "Hunter2\r"
    interact
}
```

which will may need improvements for error handling, timeouts, matching 
the shell prompt better, etc.