# Run a bash script stored on a screen on my server from a local machine remotely

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I did this:

```
ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName"
```

Now I want to add a bash script command to this line so that the command is executed then the screen detaches.

## edit:

so I want to do so

```
ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName bash bashing.sh"
```

bashing.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "testing it";
```

but actually nothing happens when I run the command over ssh.

Even when I just from the server run this command only `screen -dm -S screenName bash bashing.sh`.

## edit 1:

I tried everything so far in the answers and comments and even in the suggested question as duplicate but nothing works for me, so any help would be still very appreciated.

Sincerely

Comment: Its not working

Comment: "Sure it is - no, it's not - sure it is...". Please add failure details to your question.

Comment: ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName *want to run bash script here* "
======
so I did it like this
ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName sh bashScript.sh"
======
and like this
ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName ./bashScript.sh"
==========
and like this
ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName bash bashScript.sh" 
=======
and none of this run the script

Comment: edit your question do not answer in comment please. Comment maybe deleted and are not made to last.

Comment: @OmarK.Aly where is your bash script ?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87405/53092

Comment: @Kiwy : but could you explain how I could tweak those commands to use with screen command also. I mean to run a script on screen over ssh not just running a script over ssh

Comment: @Kiwy I edited my question so it contains it now

Comment: @OmarK.Aly WHERE not what. is it on your laptop or your server.

Comment: @Kiwy oh sorry ... Its on the server it self

Comment: your problem is that you should use the fullpath of your script on the server. or your script need to be in the PATH. `ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName bash /path/to/bashing.sh"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75190/discussion-between-omar-k-aly-and-kiwy).

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName sleep 123"
```

Comment: That kills the screen after the sleep time is done

I want to run a command and keep the screen alive just detach from it

Comment: `ssh -f user@host "screen -dm -S screenName myscript"` where myscript does something like `sleep 123; bash`.

Comment: @Nick actually my script should do this ====> 
#!/bin/bash
echo "testing it"; ==== And instead of myscript I just used my script name ===> "bashing.sh" .... is that right ?